# Error converting string to float after deployment c#

Tags: c#, .net, casting, numbers, type-conversion

i have a format exception , when i want to convert string to float after the deployment of  c# windows application .

i tried

```
string  str1 = "12.4",
float str2 = float.parse(str1);  
// it works on my computer but after deployment NOT !
```

when i run the code in my computer it works perfectly but when i run it in other computers i have a 'format_exception' when i add Numbers Like "123.4"
i try to install other frameworks but Nothing changed

Comment: First try providing code that actually compiles. You mean `string str1 = "12.4"; float str2 = float.Parse(str1);`, right?

Comment: Captain obvious here, what about making the variable str2 a float?

Comment: How can it run in your computer in the first place... That is the question actually...

Comment: Yes, as the answers already appeared (quite obviously), the problem is that the other computers probably use a different decimal separator. For example in my country (Hungary) the separator is comma, so your example fails on my computer. `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as the answers noted. Just to give an actual explanation ;)

Comment: thank u i'il try that code and i'il tell you if it works :D

Answer (score 2):

There are different cultures on your computer and on server computer.

Use:

```
float number = float.Parse(str, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: but it works on my computer and in other computers i have that error

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there are different cultures installed on those systems.

You should try this:

```
string str1 = "12.4";
float flt1 = float.Parse(str1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It will use `.` as decimal separator.

You can specify other culture info's by e.g.: using the calling thread's UI culture info: `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`

The `float.Parse` is culture dependent as stated by msdn:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/2thct5cb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

which is machine dependent.